# Issue installing version 10 on a new DNN 9.2.2

Tags: installation, 2sxc

I'm trying to install the blog app and keep getting an error message.

```
05/26/2019 20:49:27
Admin Alert
host 

2sxc-Api Auto-Log Exception 2sInst[3e Path http://enjoythisworld.com/deskt 
2sxc-Api:Auto-Log Exception

2sInst[3e]:Path: http://enjoythisworld.com/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-sys/installer/installpackage?packageUrl=https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/5EMutByRNEWtODu1sMkpDg/Download/2sxcApp_Blog_03.00.02.zip

2sInst[3e]DNN.Enviro[1b]Dnn.Publsh[70]:()

2sInst[3e]:install package:https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/5EMutByRNEWtODu1sMkpDg/Download/2sxcApp_Blog_03.00.02.zip

2sInst[3e]Dnn.MapA2I[53]:get appid from instance for Z:2 Mod:451 not found = null

2sInst[3e]Zip.Imp[6f]:import zip from url:https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/5EMutByRNEWtODu1sMkpDg/Download/2sxcApp_Blog_03.00.02.zip, isApp:True

2sInst[3e]Zip.Imp[6f]:try to download:https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/5EMutByRNEWtODu1sMkpDg/Download/2sxcApp_Blog_03.00.02.zip to:C:\Inetpub\vhosts\enjoythisworld.com\httpdocs\desktopmodules\tosic_sexycontent_\4po5clpp.vke.zip

Server Name: GenericAU04



Check
05/26/2019 20:49:27
General Exception
host 
Enjoy This World 
AbsoluteURL /desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-sys/installer/installpackage Defa 
AbsoluteURL:/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-sys/installer/installpackage

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:f9b14e08-800d-4577-b7f3-4751cf4e96ec

AssemblyVersion:

PortalId:-1

UserId:-1

TabId:-1

RawUrl:

Referrer:

UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:EUTd+51qrnU8qi8gRlrnBDlmOGY=

Message:An error occurred while installing the app: Could not download app package from 'https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/5EMutByRNEWtODu1sMkpDg/Download/2sxcApp_Blog_03.00.02.zip'.

StackTrace:

at ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.InstallerController.InstallPackage(String packageUrl) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Sxc WebApi\InstallerController.cs:line 51 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
InnerMessage:Could not download app package from 'https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/5EMutByRNEWtODu1sMkpDg/Download/2sxcApp_Blog_03.00.02.zip'.

InnerStackTrace:

at ToSic.Eav.Apps.ImportExport.ZipImport.ImportZipFromUrl(String packageUrl, Boolean isAppImport) at ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.InstallerController.InstallPackage(String packageUrl) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Sxc WebApi\InstallerController.cs:line 32
Source:ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:

Server Name: GenericAU04
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your server doesn't have an internet connection - maybe communication between the server and the internet is prohibited. To work around this, download the app directly from the app catalog and upload/install it from the zip.

Best, iJungleboy

Comment: The server does have internet.  Could you elaborate on the option to upload and install manually.

Comment: you can always download apps from 2sxc.org/apps and then use the down-arrow-button to install the zips.

Comment: It installed fine from the down arrow thanks.  I've reported the other issue to you with error messages after I removed the demo items.